# 'mvn release:perform' takes too long when deploying to Archiva

Tags: maven-release-plugin, archiva

'mvn release:perform' takes too long to deploy artifacts to Archiva. The logs shows that the 'release:perform' do its job quickly (test, package, source, javadoc...) but it takes too match time to complete download of 'maven-metadat.xml' from Archiva. Exceuting the same download request using a browser takes also too match time.

Anybody knows how to push Archiva to be quicker?

Warm regards

Younes Ouadi

**More details about the issue I'm facing. Hope this help to get it resolved/answered.**

Hello dears,

I'm using maven release plugin to release my project artifacts to Archiva. release:prepare works nicely. However, release:perform takes too long. I have a project with aroung 150 artifacts. The last try of 'release:perform' has took almost 10 hours.

I have checked the logs and figure out that Archiva takes too much time to reply when maven tries to download 'maven-metadata.xml' of each artifact. In the same time, uploading project artifacts takes reasonable time. The logs below conforms my findings.

Anybody can help to figure out why Archiva takes too much time to react to downloading 'maven-metadata.xml' of each artifact?

The logs are as follow for one artifact. The same behavior is witnessed for all the 150 artifacts. I have put deliberately empty lines between each request just to easy follow up.

**1) Logs of 'mvn release:perform' (no time stamping but, the sequence requests is nice to know from maven stand point)**
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ com.natisco.commons.exceptions ---

[INFO] Uploading: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.jar
[INFO] Uploaded: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.jar (16 KB at 127.6 KB/sec)

[INFO] Uploading: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.pom
[INFO] Uploaded: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.pom (2 KB at 47.8 KB/sec)

[INFO] Downloading: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml (343 B at 0.0 KB/sec)

[INFO] Uploading: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Uploaded: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml (371 B at 6.8 KB/sec)

[INFO] Uploading: .../com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-sources.jar
[INFO] Uploaded: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-sources.jar (11 KB at 295.8 KB/sec)

[INFO] Uploading: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-javadoc.jar
[INFO] Uploaded: .../com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-javadoc.jar (75 KB at 1487.2 KB/sec)

**2) Logs of Archiva as extracted from '2011_11_13.request.log'**
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:24:14 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.jar HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:24:15 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.jar.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:24:15 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.jar.md5 HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"

127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:24:15 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.pom HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:24:15 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.pom.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:24:15 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4.pom.md5 HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"

127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:24:15 +0000] "GET /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 200 343 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "GET /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 200 60 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/maven-metadata.xml.md5 HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"

127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-sources.jar HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-sources.jar.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-sources.jar.md5 HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"

127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-javadoc.jar HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"
127.0.0.1 -  -  [13/Nov/2011:08:27:52 +0000] "PUT /archiva/repository/internal/com/natisco/com.natisco.commons.exceptions/0.4/com.natisco.commons.exceptions-0.4-javadoc.jar.sha1 HTTP/1.1" 201 0 "-" "Apache-Maven/3.0.3 (Java 1.6.0_14; Linux 2.6.27.41-170.2.117.fc10.i686)"

Thank you in advance for your help.

Younes Ouadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slow requests are the `GET` for the metadata file. What this probably means is that it is
trying to proxy from an external source that is slow or timing out.

Check your proxy connectors and disable any that may be slow. You should also add whitelists
/ blacklists to make sure external sources are not used to request `com.natisco.*` artefacts.

(See also thread on users@archiva.apache.org: http://s.apache.org/Xph)

Comment: Brett, you are right. I have added my own domain in the blacklist of all my proxy connectors. Now, Archiva replies within good time to download requests referencing nonexistent artifacts (maven-metadata.xml in the above case). Thank you very much for your helop